# Mod_Python: Publisher Handler vs PSP Handler

Tags: python, mod-python

I've been testing out Mod_python and it seems that there are two ways of producing python code using:-

- Publisher Handler
- PSP Handler

I've gotten both to work at the same time however, should I use one over the other? PSP resembles PHP a lot but Publisher seems to resemble python more. Is there an advantage over using one (speed, ease of use, etc.)?

Comment: You should not be starting a new project in mod_python. It is deprecated and un-supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the mod_python (project was abandoned long ago) but nowadays Python applications are using wsgi (mod_wsgi or uwsgi). If you are using apache, mod_wsgi is easy to configure, for nginx use the uwsgi.